# JavaMail SSL with no Authentication trust certificate regardless

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I have a local mail server (hMailServer) with SSL (port 465) and a self-signed certificate.

Domain is "foobar.com"

I have setup my `Properties` to enable ssl, disable auth, and trust any host

```
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "*");
```

If I send the message through the static call to `Transport.send()`
The email gets delivered.

If I try to get a `transport` instance from the session then I get

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

**How does the static call avoids the SSLHandshakeException?**

Here's my tester code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "127.0.0.1");
    props.put("mail.debug", "false");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.timeout", "60000");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
    props.put("mail.smtp.sendpartial", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "*");
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("mrFoo@foobar.com"));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("you@foobar.com"));
    message.setSubject("Just a Test " + new Date());
    message.setText("Hello World");

    //Comment and uncomment to test   
    Transport.send(message, message.getAllRecipients());

    //Transport t = session.getTransport("smtps");
    //t.connect();
    //t.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    //t.close();
}
```

This is a local system hidden from the outside, so I am not worried about man in the middle attack generating their own certificates to bypass the SSL Handshake...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You asked for an "smtps" transport.  You set the properties for the "smtp" transport.  Since you've set the "mail.smtp.ssl.enable" property to "true", you can just ask for an "smtp" transport and it will use SSL.

Comment: That is, do `Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp")` instead of `..."smtps")`, right, in the out commented lines at the end of the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This the solution for JavaMail SSL with no Authentication trust certificate using Spring framework, change your .xml file  as describe below.You can see the solution in the snapshot  [See the image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcitE.png)

javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory 
                true

change it to **false** if you want mail server must be in ssl

Answer (score -4):

The best solution for this is to use the following line

```
    MailSSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new MailSSLSocketFactory();
    socketFactory.setTrustAllHosts(true);
```