# Sending email using godaddy account using java

Tags: java, email

I am trying to send emails using my godaddy account in java. Below is my code.

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.transport.protocol","smtp" );
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true" );
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "false");
props.put("mail.smtp.host","smtpout.secureserver.net");

props.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port","465");
props.put("mail.debug","true");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port","465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback","false");


 Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
 Session session=Session.getInstance(props,auth);
 session.setDebug(true);

 // -- Create a new message --
 Transport transport=session.getTransport();

 Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
 // -- Set the FROM and TO fields --
 msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(""email@domain.com));
 msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("email@domain.com", false));
 msg.setSubject("subject");
 msg.setText("Message");

 transport.connect();
 Transport.send(msg);
 transport.close();
```

While executing I'm getting the below Exception.

> com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtpout.secureserver.net , 465; timeout -1;
>     nested exception is:
>       java.net.UnknownHostException: smtpout.secureserver.net

PS:When i use gmail account for authentication its working fine and email sent successfully. When i use godaddy account the exception throws.

Please guide me how to solve this issue...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you sure the hostname of the SMTP server is correct?

Comment: I have deleted my answer,I dont have godaddy account so can not check at my side.Just go throgh this article http://www.javaquery.com/2011/09/how-to-send-mail-from-godaddy-java-mail.html

Comment: @SpringLearner I tried the same from the link you provide but it also throws the same exception.

Comment: @Stefan ya i am sure i follow the same process which is given in the link provide by SpringLearner...

Answer (score 4):

My configuration in SpringBoot (replace domainname.com to your domainname)

```
spring:
  mail:
    host: smtpout.secureserver.net
    port: 465
    username: info@domainname.com
    password: password
    protocol: smtp
    properties.mail.smtp:
      auth: true
      ssl.enable: true
      ssl.trust: "*"
```

Also I had to add `mimeMessageHelper.setFrom("info@domainname.com");` before sending the mail (else it was taking my system name and gave an error) and this setup worked.

Comment: This info was very useful,and it worked for me, thank you Krishna Kumar, especially the small piece of code mimeMessageHelper.setFrom("info@domainname.com"); worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is complete method that is working absolutely fine for me (I have also used an attachment in the message) :

```
private void sendUsingSmtp(MailDetail mailDetail) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.host", "smtpout.secureserver.net");
        props.put("mail.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.username", "info@domainName.com");
        props.put("mail.password", “password”);
        props.put("mail.protocol", "smtp");

        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "*");


        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("info@domainName”, “password");
            }
        });
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        try {
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("info@domainName.com", false);
            msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(“targetEmail@gmail.com"));
            msg.setSubject("Test Subject.");
            msg.setContent("Test Content.", "text/html");
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());

            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setContent("Test Content.", "text/html");

            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            attachPart.attachFile("/var/tmp/abc.txt");
            multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
            msg.setContent(multipart);
            Transport.send(msg);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[JavaMail SSL with no Authentication trust certificate regardless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488938/javamail-ssl-with-no-authentication-trust-certificate-regardless/33966660#33966660)

```
    MailSSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new MailSSLSocketFactory();
    socketFactory.setTrustAllHosts(true);
```

requires javax.mail 1.5.2 and greater